# java rmi socket connection timeout without real attempt to connect

Tags: java, sockets, rmi

I have rmi client which connects to several rmi servers on different machines. I sometimes get connection timeout on client. It happens randomly and when I find it out and try to connect to server again it is always successful. There isn't any firewall between machines.

I tried to capture network traffic with Wireshark and there isn no outgoing SYN packet from client so it seems like there is no attempt to establish the connection.

What can be cause of it? How can I find out what is going on there?

Edit: logs from RMI:

```
4:02:44 AM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint newSocket
FINER: task-6786: opening socket to [c1w7IE10-0059:1099]
4:02:44 AM sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory createSocket
FINE: task-6786: host: c1w7IE10-0059, port: 1099
```

Port and host are correct but no  SYN packet sent to the host.

Edit: stacktrace

```
ERROR: Error: com.kerio.at.lib.exception.KRemoteOperationFailedException: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: c1w7IE10-0059; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
com.kerio.at.lib.exception.KRemoteOperationFailedException: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: c1w7IE10-0059; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.kerio.at.lib.testmanager.rmi.client.TestManagerClient.connect(TestManagerClient.java:88)
    at com.kerio.at.lib.cml.scheduling.RunTestTask.connectToNode(RunTestTask.java:485)
    at com.kerio.at.lib.cml.scheduling.RunTestTask.call(RunTestTask.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: c1w7IE10-0059; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.kerio.at.lib.testmanager.rmi.client.TestManagerClient.connect(TestManagerClient.java:59)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Maybe post your code if you want help....We cannot guess what is wrong without it.

Comment: Can you increase socket timeout using system property `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout` or from program??
Then check it again.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Why? That's a read timeout at the client. Fiddling around with it won't solve a connect problem.

Comment: I get this from time to time too. It always turns out to be the DNS and host name resolving issue for me.

Comment: Is it that the `ulimit` issue at your client side? Maybe, if you're trying to create more than specified(by ulimit) number of connections, it may not attempt to connect(Maybe). But, you also say, when you try to re-connect it manually, then it does get connect!

Comment: Where is the actual error message and stack trace for this question?

Comment: Is the hostname `c1w7IE10-005` what you expect to see? And can you ping it from tthe client? If not, see the RMI FAQ item A.1.

Comment: What do you mean by 'without real attempt to connect'? There is an extremely real attempt to connect in the stack trace. `Naming.lookup()` connects to the Registry.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible causes:

- an external firewall is blocking the requests
- an internal firewall is blocking the requests (think "iptables")
- if you are on a virtual machine, the requests are being lost due to an intermittent or load-related problem with the virtual networks
- it could be an intermittent routing problem; e.g. if your machine has two NICs, then traffic could be misrouted due to misconfigured DHCP
- your application could occasionally using the wrong IP address; e.g. if it occasionally used a loopback address that might not show up in your Wireshark captures.

Some of these we can tentatively or positively eliminate.  But be careful, because it is possible that your knowledge of your local networking environment is incomplete or out of date.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am pretty sure that firewall is not an issue. The machines are virtual but I capture traffic on client machine so I suppose I would see outgoing packet there which than could be lost but this is not the case. Same with misconfigured DHCP. So there remains your last point. Is there any way how to confirm or disprove it?

Answer (score 0):

I turned out to be DNS problem. I switched off dns cache (windows service 'dns client') and the problem disappeared.

Thanks bili for his advice.